# How to use mediaplayer.stop()?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Java in combination with Android at the moment. Today I wanted to learn about mediaplayers. I've made three buttons: play, pause and stop. Play and pause work properly, but whenever I press the stop button, the music stops and I'm not able to start it again. I have to reopen the app to let the music play again. What is my mistake?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MediaPlayer mymediaplayer;

    public void Play (View view){
        mymediaplayer.start();
    }

    public void pause (View view){
        mymediaplayer.pause();
    }

    public void stop (View view){
        mymediaplayer.stop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mymediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mysoundfile);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have reset media player after stop

```
mymediaplayer.reset();
mymediaplayer.setDataSource(PATH);
mymediaplayer.prepare();
mymediaplayer.start();
```

Comment: So I insert your first three lines into my stop method after mp.stop() ?

Comment: put this method in play method

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: I tried this, it says it doesn't know "mp.prepare()" and "mp.setDataSource(...)"
I checked the link, but there are no usages of those arguments, just explanations which don't help me...

```java

 public void Play (View view){
        mymediaplayer.reset();
        mymediaplayer.setDataSource("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysoundfile);
        mymediaplayer.prepare();
        mymediaplayer.start();
    }
```